# Same Regex works different in Java and Elasticsearch

Tags: java, regex, elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5

I am using a pattern tokenizer inside a JAVA Program. I am using the regex: "\p{Punct}{1}"

I also created a JAVA program with the same regex. But, when I compared the result of both the JAVA program and the elasticsearch analyzer with the same pattern, they were different.

The code inside my JAVA file is:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.*;

public class characters {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String userInput = "HTTps://www.google.cOM/";
        userInput = userInput.toLowerCase();

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\p{Punct}{1}");
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        Matcher m = pattern.matcher(userInput);
        while (m.find()) {
            list.add(m.group());
        }
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

The above program gave the below result:

```
[:, /, /, ., ., /]
```

The code inside the elasticsearch pattern file is:

```
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.Tokenizer;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.pattern.PatternTokenizer;
import org.elasticsearch.common.regex.Regex;
import org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Settings;
import org.elasticsearch.env.Environment;
import org.elasticsearch.index.IndexSettings;
import org.elasticsearch.index.analysis.AbstractTokenizerFactory;

import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class UrlTokenizerFactory extends AbstractTokenizerFactory {

    private final Pattern pattern;
    private final int group;

    public UrlTokenizerFactory(IndexSettings indexSettings, Environment environment, String name, Settings settings) {
        super(indexSettings, name, settings);

        String sPattern = settings.get("pattern", "\\p{Punct}{1}");

        if (sPattern == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("pattern is missing for [" + name + "] tokenizer of type 'pattern'");
        }

        this.pattern = Regex.compile(sPattern, settings.get("flags"));
        this.group = settings.getAsInt("group", -1);
    }

    @Override
    public Tokenizer create() {
        return new PatternTokenizer(pattern, group);
    }
}
```

It is generating the below result:

```
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "https",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 5,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "www",
      "start_offset" : 8,
      "end_offset" : 11,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 1
    },
    {
      "token" : "google",
      "start_offset" : 12,
      "end_offset" : 18,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 2
    },
    {
      "token" : "com",
      "start_offset" : 19,
      "end_offset" : 22,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 3
    }
  ]
```

The desired result is that of the JAVA file. But, I'm getting a different one in elasticsearch's case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by simply changing the value of

```
this.group = settings.getAsInt("group", -1);
```

to:

```
this.group = settings.getAsInt("group", 0);
```

inside my patternTokenizer file.